# how to properly install workfolio on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

hello please I have this application workfolio  and my organization has asked us to install it to track our working hours and task it's available for many operating systems including Ubuntu
but with Ubuntu when I install and run the application, a blanc window opens up and self-terminates after 5secons.

I am actually confused and really need help
here is the website link [workfolio](https://app.workfolio.io)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? The link you provided takes me to the login page. If it is a commercial software, you should [ask for support from the developers](https://workfolio.tawk.help/article/workfolio-linux-application-installation-guide).

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to try the instructions here https://workfolio.tawk.help/article/workfolio-linux-application-installation-guide?

> **Installation Steps for Linux/Ubuntu App:**
>
> Step 1: Download this file
>
> Step 2: (Navigate to the destination location, below path may differ
> in your system) cd Downloads
>
> Step 3: sudo dpkg -i workfolio_0.1.30_amd64.deb (or) sudo apt install
> ./workfolio_0.1.30_amd64.deb
>
> Installation Completed

Comment: This is a comment not an answer. An answer is a complete solution. The OP says it is installed and just does not work correctly.

Comment: yh that was the guid i followed during installation

Comment: when i try runing the app using terminal i get 
"
Packed true
03:11:24.496 › (node:9280) electron: The default of contextIsolation is deprecated and will be changing from false to true in a future release of Electron.  See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506 for more information
[9280:0416/031125.264665:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU proces

Answer (score 0):

Tried this, and it worked for me:

Installed Workfolio via `apt`:

```
sudo apt install ./workfolio_x.x.x_amd64.deb
```

Launched using `--no-sandbox` flag:

```
workfolio --no-sandbox
```

This flag is vital linked to Workfolio's Electron framework. Disabling it fixes blank window and termination issues.

Give it a shot. Hope this solves things.